# When do we use $2\pi$ vs using $\pi$ in finding the volume of a region?

Tags: calculus, volume

I'm taking Calculus 2 and I have this question:

I've seen that sometimes finding the integral volume of a  rotated shape in the $xy$-plane is multiplied by $2\pi$, and other times it is only multiplied by $\pi$. Can someone please tell me the difference?

Comment: It depends on whether you are using the [washer method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disc_integration) or [shell method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_integration) to compute the volume of integration.

Comment: So then which one would use 2 pi?

Comment: Following the links could answer your question

Comment: Whoops didn't notice that, thank you everyone!

Comment: You should understand the methods you are using to know which you should use.  $2\pi$ comes from the circumference of a circle while $\pi$ usually comes from the area.  If you think about the small volumes you are adding together, you should see which to use.

Answer (score 6):

Whether to use $\pi$ or $2\pi$ depends on the choice of the two common integration methods.

1) If the disk-of-circles method is used, disk area $\pi r^2$ is applied. The integration is then over a stack of disks,

$$V = \int_a^b \pi x^2 dx$$

2) If the shell-of-cylinders method is used, cylinder circumference $2\pi r$ is applied. The integration is then through cylinder walls,

$$V=\int_a^b 2\pi xy(x)dx$$